# I'm confused about pointers again

Tags: c++, pointers

In the lecture notes for my class, there is a function

```
Obj3D * findObject (int objID) {
   Obj3D *pObj = ...
   if (pObj == 0) {
      throw BadObjectID (objID);
   return pObj;
```

Why is it that the function returns a pointer to an object, but the return type of the function is an object?

Comment: 'Obj3D * ' is pointer to object and you have it in first line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type is `Obj3D *`, which is a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an object - you have `Obj3D *pObj` - that is a pointer to an instance of `Obj3D`.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the function is `Obj3D *`, that is, a pointer to an `Obj3D`. This is exactly what the function is returning.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the function isn't an object.

```
Obj3D *findObject
```

means that findObject returns a pointer to an Obj3D variable. It could be written as

```
Obj3D* findObject
```

too.

Answer (score 1):

no the function declaration says it will return a pointer of type Obj3D. the declaration to return a pointer in a function is`OBJ * functionname(input) {`